# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined (Chart.js & Angular/Cordova)

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova

I'm trying to draw a chart after function call. I'm receiving this as an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

Here is my **HTML** file:

```
<ion-content>

    <ng-template #guest>      
    <div>
      <button ion-button block (click)="auth.googleLogin()"><i class="fa fa-google"></i>   Connect Google</button>
      <button ion-button block (click)="auth.facebookLogin()"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>   Connect Facebook</button>
    </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Bar Chart
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <canvas #barCanvas></canvas>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    </ng-template>

</ion-content>
```

and my **.TS** file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-drawingchart',
  templateUrl: 'drawingchart.html'
})

export class drawingChart{

  @ViewChild('barCanvas') barCanvas: ElementRef;

  barChart: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public auth: AuthService) 
  {

  }

  activateChart(objects)
  {
    this.barChart = new Chart(this.barCanvas.nativeElement,
      {
          type: 'bar',
          data: 
          {
              labels: [objects[0].year, objects[1].year, objects[2].year, objects[3].year],
              datasets: 
              [
                  {
                      label: Gender',
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                      stack: 'Stack 0',
                      data: 
                      [
                          objects[0].gender,
                          objects[1].gender,
                          objects[2].gender,
                          objects[3].gender
                      ]
                  }, 
                  {
                      label: 'Age',
                      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                      stack: 'Stack 0',
                      data: 
                      [
                          objects[0].age,
                          objects[1].age,
                          objects[2].age,
                          objects[3].age
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      });
  }

}
```

Please note that the function activateChart is called from another class once the user logs in and send the information to the chart function. (objects is arriving correctly)

Thank you!

Comment: Have u fixed this issue? please provide the solution?

Comment: Yes i was able to solve it as far as i remember... I'll take a look at it asap and let you know!